# Output of multiarray values with php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, output, sub-array

I'm trying to output values from a multiarray with PHP, but I can't get my head around on how  to retrieve a specific value from each entry.

Array -

```
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [image] => sample1.jpg
                )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [image] => sample2.jpg
                    )

            )

    )
```

Code -

```
if ($query) {
    foreach ( $query as $outer_array ) {
        foreach ( $outer_array as $inner_array ) {
            $html .= '<img src="' . $inner_array[image] . '" alt="" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Current output -

```
<img src="" alt="" />
<img src="" alt="" />
```

<s>This gives me blank weird results. Tried a dozen different approaches, I guess I'm just not well enough proficient in how multiarrays work.</s>

Edit: Went with another approach. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: do a var_dump($html) ,what do you get ?

Comment: @mpm, I get "string(22)" and "string(43)", I assume this is a reference to the images.

Comment: I've tried your example and it works for me, are you actually echoing the $html variable after you've done this somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the ouput becomes two empty image elements.

Comment: Then your code is working but your actual hyperlinks are not, otherwise you wouldn't be outputting the img tags at all. Right click on the empty image elements that are produced and check that the hyperlink is the correct location of the images on your site and if not update it to the correct location...

Comment: Wait, let me update the question so that you see my current output.

Comment: Do you have an example page online of this that I can take a look at...

Comment: Only localhost, sorry. But the error is so small it should really be a simple fix?

Comment: It's strange because it works perfectly for me on my localhost... You said using `$inner_array[0]['image']` works? What if you add a variable `$i = 0` before all the loops then use `$inner_array[$i]['image']` putting `$i++` after you reference it?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone Thanks, that solved half the problem. I still only get the second image value, for some reason the first value returns an "s" (!).

Comment: There is something strange at work here beyond what can be seen in your code, it would appear that it's returning an s because it is counting the first letter of the string `sample1.jpg` which is what happens when you reference a position in an array on a string... To be honest though you shouldnt have to be going through this convoluted way around it as it should just work. I re-created your array as such `$query = array( 'images' => array( array( 'image' => 'sample1.jpg' ), array( 'image' => 'sample2.jpg' ) ) );` and it worked perfectly for me in your original example. Can you try with that?

Comment: Nope, still missing that first value... I'm about to give up. This should be so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your structure is like in your example you can save one of the loops by directly looping over $query['images']:

```
if (!empty($query['images'])) {
    foreach((array) $query['images'] as $image) {
        $html .= '<img src="' . $image['image'] . '" alt="" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, though for some reason the loop doesn't run at all with this setup.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($query);`?

Comment: The same as the array mentioned above.

Comment: Then this should work. Maybe try to debug the data flow step by step using `print_r` or `var_dump` and see were it fails.

Answer (score 2):

put quotes around image first :

```
$inner_array['image']
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't help though. I assume this is good practice for referencing values?

Comment: It certainly is. Otherwise php interprets image as a constant and only after the lookup fails it falls back to 'image'. Except when using numbers as keys you should always use quotes. Enable your error display and set your error_reporting level to E_ALL for development. This way the PHP interpreter will point such issues out for you.

Comment: This isn't good practise, this is `THE` way to do it, otherwise you will end up with `Use of undefined constant` notices

Answer (score 0):

if $query represents the outer most array then you just need to change

```
foreach ( $query as $outer_array )
```

to

```
foreach ( $query['images'] as $outer_array )
```

so it should look like:

```
    if (isset($query['images']) && is_array($query['images'])) {

    foreach ( $query['images'] as $inner_array ) {            

            $html .= '<img src="' . $inner_array['image'] . '" alt="" />';

    }
}
```